# How to show amount of items after text filtering?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `Angular` and `Ionic` to show some lists and filter those lists. What I want to achieve now, is to show the right amount of numbers of lists that are shown after text filtering.

To show you what is going wrong, I have illustrated it in Codepen:

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLJXQP**

So what's going wrong? Well, try to filter the list by querying something random. You will see that it will keep saying that there are "50 persons", while you have none if you would query "MichaelBlabla", for example.

So what I want to achieve is, is to show the right amount of items that are shown (or not shown). So if nothing is shown, I want to see 0 persons.

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="item my-item"
      collection-repeat="item in contacts | filter:{name:blablabla} | orderBy:'first_name' | searchContacts:search" 
      collection-item-height="60"
      collection-item-width="'100%'">
      <img ng-src="http://placekitten.com/60/{{55 + ($index % 10)}}">
      {{item.first_name+' '+item.last_name}}
    </a>
  </div>

  <p>Showing {{contacts.length}} Persons</p>
```

How can I do this? I am getting the feeling that this filter, is just not updating the query at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic's `collection-repeat` directive doesn't support [`ng-repeat`'s ability to use an alias expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to store the intermediate results of the repeater after the filters have been applied, so you have to jump through a few hoops. Here's the version of your code that would use `ng-repeat`, just to set the baseline:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in contacts | filter:{name:blablabla} | orderBy:'first_name' | searchContacts:search as results">
    <p>Number of Results: {{ results.length }}</p>
</div>
```

But since you're using `collection-repeat`, you have to do the following:

First, in the controller, set up a scope value that can hold the count value. Note that this needs to be a hash-object, like `$scope.collectionData = {length: 0 };`. (Skipping over this for now, it's a scoping issue that'll be covered later.) Second, in your template, the `collection-repeat` directive needs to be used in an assignment-type fashion. And third, you need to hack in a hidden element that we can use as a vessel for assigning the count value to the `collectionData.length` value:

```
<div collection-repeat="item in (results = (contacts | filter:{name:blablabla} | orderBy:'first_name' | searchContacts:search))">
    <span ng-bind="collectionData.length = results.length" ng-show="false"></span>
    <p>Number of Results: {{ collectionData.length }}</p>
</div>
```

I've updated your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbdQMb.

As for the scoping issue I skipped over: using the object notation (`<span ng-bind="collectionData.length = ..." ...></span>`) in the assignment forces angular to search through the various scopes until it finds the `collectionData` object. This is because we're working inside of the scope of the `collection-repeat` directive, so if you tried something like `<span ng-bind="myCountVal = results.length" ..></span>`, that `myCountVal` would be assigned to the scope of the `collection-repeat` directive, which would prevent you from using it *outside of the scope of the `collection-repeat` directive*, which is really the key goal here: repeat a list of filtered items, and show the count somewhere on the page outside of the list itself.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that, my filter doesn't work anymore. You can see it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLJXQP

Comment: I've updated my answer & the codepen, give it another go and let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks man. Almost there... I want to show the text every time, so not only when there are no persons. Can we do that too?

Comment: Which text are you referring to?

Comment: The text with "there are x persons"

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the codepen that I copied from, but you can use `<span ng-bind="'There are ' + collectionData.length + ' persons'"></span>` as a starting point, that should work anywhere in the template.

Comment: Thanks YellowShark. Upvoted and accepted the answer.